# Portable and interruptible wait for a thread

Tags: c++, c++11

**The problem**

I'm trying to use a simple, portable way to perform an interruptible sleep for a thread. Another requirement I have is about the use of SIGSTOP/SIGCONT, if the program is suspended the wait must performs without taking into account the suspension. Example: I'm waiting for 5 seconds, after 1 second the program is suspended, after 1 one minute is restored, the wait should run again waiting 4 seconds.

**My analisys**

`std::condition_variable::wait_for()` and `std::condition_variable::wait_until()` methods use a monothonic time only starting from gcc 10 and glibc 2.6 [bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41861). On previous versions or where there's no platform support, i.e. `pthread_cond_clockwait()` not available, the system clock is used. Using the system clock however can have side effects like a timeout too early or too late if the system clock is changed by human or automatically (ex. NTP). In addition the `wait_for()` and `wait_until()` can trigger too early if we stop the process via `SIGSTOP` because the system clock or steady clock are evaluated again and since the whole time is running but our process is frozen, when we start the process again using `SIGCONT` every wait is triggered.

**Possible solutions**

It seems there's only one way to sleep in a reliable way even on older platforms, calling `select` system call. In addition select behavior is ok for my requirements and it can be interrupted using the self pipe trick for example.

**The question**

Is my analysis correct? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you only interested in certain operating systems or kernels? That may influence the scope of a solution. Further, if GCC 10 offers this feature, you may be able to backport it to earlier compilers as well, if upgrading the compiler is too much an effort.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Ideally I'd like to use a general approach, c++11 was really good but as I said seems not reliable at all. I'm interested in windows and linux at least but not limited to these two. Changing compiler is not an option for me, it would be a pain to impose a newer version of gcc and glibc for older systems.

Comment: Okay... funny: Since you mentioned signals, I already ruled out Microsoft Windows as possible target.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The signal requirement is applicable only on platforms where it's possible to perform this kind of suspension of course.